# MySQL query using 'in' operator: why different results w/ quotes?

Tags: mysql, sql, coercion

I've tracked down a weird MySQL problem to the two different ways I was performing a query.  When you boil everything down, this way returns more results:

```
SELECT DISTINCT <stuff> FROM <tables> 
WHERE promo_detail_store_id in (8214, 8217, 4952, 8194, ...)
```

This change to the WHERE clause produces a subset of those results:

```
WHERE promo_detail_store_id in ('8214, 8217, 4952, 8194, ...')
```

(promo_detail_store_id is defined as a BIGINT in a MyISAM table.)

Originally that list of store_ids was much longer, and I started cutting it shorter and shorter thinking maybe there was some weird limits on the length of a string.  But no, it holds for quite small strings/lists too.  Clearly something is going on behind the scenes involving type coercion and maybe how the 'in' operator works.  Can someone enlighten me?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`WHERE promo_detail_store_id in (8214, 8217, 4952, 8194, ...)`

means

```
WHERE promo_detail_store_id = 8214 
OR  promo_detail_store_id = 8217
OR promo_detail_store_id = 4952 
OR promo_detail_store_id = 8194
OR ...
```

---

```
WHERE promo_detail_store_id in ('8214, 8217, 4952, 8194, ...')
```

means

```
 WHERE promo_detail_store_id = '8214, 8217, 4952, 8194, ...'
```

`'8214, 8217, 4952, 8194, ...'` will cast to number to be `8214`, so it will be

```
WHERE promo_detail_store_id = 8214
```

Answer (score 3):

The second condition is effectively equivalent to `WHERE promo_detail_store_id IN (8214)`, because you're comparing a `BIGINT` to a `TEXT` and the text is cast to an integer value, which disregards everything from the first non-numeric character to the end of the string.